# Asynchronous digital clock while send data to serial port

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application and a digital clock made with a Kinetis development platform. The WPF send a initial time and 5 alarms. But when the Kinetis send the notification that an alarm was activated, the WPF app read it and show as a message box but the digital clock that is in the app stop while the message box is activated. How can I do to keep the clock running?

[image]

CS

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        SerialPort sp;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblTime.Content = Convert.ToDateTime(lblTime.Content).AddSeconds(1).ToLongTimeString();
            int btr = sp.BytesToRead;
            if (btr != 0)
            {
                string alarma = char.ConvertFromUtf32(sp.ReadChar());
                MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("La alarma " + alarma + " se activo", "Alarma", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int intHoras = Convert.ToInt32(Horas.Text == "" ? "-1" : Horas.Text);
            int intMinutos = Convert.ToInt32(Minutos.Text == "" ? "-1" : Minutos.Text);

            int intHoras1 = Convert.ToInt32(Horas1.Text == "" ? "-1" : Horas1.Text);
            int intMinutos1 = Convert.ToInt32(Minutos1.Text == "" ? "-1" : Minutos1.Text);

            int intHoras2 = Convert.ToInt32(Horas2.Text == "" ? "-1" : Horas2.Text);
            int intMinutos2 = Convert.ToInt32(Minutos2.Text == "" ? "-1" : Minutos2.Text);

            int intHoras3 = Convert.ToInt32(Horas3.Text == "" ? "-1" : Horas3.Text);
            int intMinutos3 = Convert.ToInt32(Minutos3.Text == "" ? "-1" : Minutos3.Text);

            int intHoras4 = Convert.ToInt32(Horas4.Text == "" ? "-1" : Horas4.Text);
            int intMinutos4 = Convert.ToInt32(Minutos4.Text == "" ? "-1" : Minutos4.Text);

            int intHoras5 = Convert.ToInt32(Horas5.Text == "" ? "-1" : Horas5.Text);
            int intMinutos5 = Convert.ToInt32(Minutos5.Text == "" ? "-1" : Minutos5.Text);

            if ((intHoras <= 24) && (intMinutos <= 60) && (intHoras >= 0) && (intMinutos >= 0) &&
                (intHoras1 <= 24) && (intMinutos1 <= 60) && (intHoras1 >= 0) && (intMinutos1 >= 0) &&
                (intHoras2 <= 24) && (intMinutos2 <= 60) && (intHoras2 >= 0) && (intMinutos2 >= 0) &&
                (intHoras3 <= 24) && (intMinutos3 <= 60) && (intHoras3 >= 0) && (intMinutos3 >= 0) &&
                (intHoras4 <= 24) && (intMinutos4 <= 60) && (intHoras4 >= 0) && (intMinutos4 >= 0) &&
                (intHoras5 <= 24) && (intMinutos5 <= 60) && (intHoras5 >= 0) && (intMinutos5 >= 0))
            {
                sp = new SerialPort("COM3");
                sp.BaudRate = 19200;
                sp.Open();

                WriteTime(sp, intHoras, intMinutos);
                WriteTime(sp, intHoras1, intMinutos1);
                WriteTime(sp, intHoras2, intMinutos2);
                WriteTime(sp, intHoras3, intMinutos3);
                WriteTime(sp, intHoras4, intMinutos4);
                WriteTime(sp, intHoras5, intMinutos5);

                DateTime date = new DateTime();
                TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, intHoras, intMinutos + 2);
                date = date + ts;
                lblTime.Content = date.ToLongTimeString();
                DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
                timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
                timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
                timer.Start();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Ingresaste datos incorrectos", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }

        private void WriteTime(SerialPort sp, int intHoras, int intMinutos)
        {
            List<byte[]> horas = getVectorNumber(intHoras);
            List<byte[]> minutos = getVectorNumber(intMinutos);
            foreach (byte[] item in horas)
            {
                sp.Write(item, 0, 1);
            }
            foreach (byte[] item in minutos)
            {
                sp.Write(item, 0, 1);
            }
        }

        private List<byte[]> getVectorNumber(int number)
        {
            List<byte[]> result = new List<byte[]>();
            result.Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(number / 10)));
            result.Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(number % 10)));
            return result;
        }

        #region NumericValidation
        private void textBoxValue_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = !TextBoxTextAllowed(e.Text);
        }

        private void textBoxValue_Pasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(String)))
            {
                String Text1 = (String)e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(String));
                if (!TextBoxTextAllowed(Text1)) e.CancelCommand();
            }
            else e.CancelCommand();
        }
        #endregion

        private Boolean TextBoxTextAllowed(String Text2)
        {
            return Array.TrueForAll<Char>(Text2.ToCharArray(),
                delegate(Char c) { return Char.IsDigit(c) || Char.IsControl(c); });
        }


    }
```

XAML

```
![<Window x:Class="DigitalPITClock.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="579.254" Width="877.835">
    <Grid Background="Gray" Margin="0,0,-4.8,-55">
        <Label Name="lblTime" FontSize="48" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="297,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="83" Width="269" RenderTransformOrigin="0.495,0.468"/>
        <Label Content="Ingrese las horas y los minutos" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="324,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="15px"/>
        <Label Content="Horas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="270,157,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="59" FontSize="15px"/>
        <TextBox Name="Horas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="363,157,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.906,0.034" Height="29" Width="37" PreviewTextInput="textBoxValue_PreviewTextInput" DataObject.Pasting="textBoxValue_Pasting" MaxLength="2" FontSize="15px"/>
        <Label Content="Minutos" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="445,157,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="29" Width="71" FontSize="15px"/>
        <TextBox Name="Minutos" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="544,157,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.906,0.034" Height="29" Width="38" PreviewTextInput="textBoxValue_PreviewTextInput" DataObject.Pasting="textBoxValue_Pasting" MaxLength="2" FontSize="15px"/>

        <Label Content="Alarma 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="171,207,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.487,0.445"/>
        <Label Content="Horas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,253,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="59" FontSize="15px"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Horas1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="118,253,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.906,0.034" Height="29" Width="37" PreviewTextInput="textBoxValue_PreviewTextInput" DataObject.Pasting="textBoxValue_Pasting" MaxLength="2" FontSize="15px"/>
        <Label Content="Minutos" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,253,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="29" Width="71" FontSize="15px"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Minutos1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="299,253,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.906,0.034" Height="29" Width="38" PreviewTextInput="textBoxValue_PreviewTextInput" DataObject.Pasting="textBoxValue_Pasting" MaxLength="2" FontSize="15px"/>

        <Label Content="Alarma 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,324,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.487,0.445"/>
        <Label Content="Horas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,363,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="59" FontSize="15px"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Horas2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="117,363,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.906,0.034" Height="29" Width="37" PreviewTextInput="textBoxValue_PreviewTextInput" DataObject.Pasting="textBoxValue_Pasting" MaxLength="2" FontSize="15px"/>
        <Label Content="Minutos" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="199,363,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="29" Width="71" FontSize="15px"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Minutos2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="298,363,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.906,0.034" Height="29" Width="38" PreviewTextInput="textBoxValue_PreviewTextInput" DataObject.Pasting="textBoxValue_Pasting" MaxLength="2" FontSize="15px"/>

        <Label Content="Alarma 3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="385,421,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.487,0.445"/>
        <Label Content="Horas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="249,473,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="59" FontSize="15px"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Horas3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="342,473,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.906,0.034" Height="29" Width="37" PreviewTextInput="textBoxValue_PreviewTextInput" DataObject.Pasting="textBoxValue_Pasting" MaxLength="2" FontSize="15px"/>
        <Label Content="Minutos" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="424,473,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="29" Width="71" FontSize="15px"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Minutos3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="523,473,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.906,0.034" Height="29" Width="38" PreviewTextInput="textBoxValue_PreviewTextInput" DataObject.Pasting="textBoxValue_Pasting" MaxLength="2" FontSize="15px"/>

        <Label Content="Alarma 4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="614,207,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.487,0.445"/>
        <Label Content="Horas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="476,258,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="59" FontSize="15px"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Horas4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="569,258,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.906,0.034" Height="29" Width="37" PreviewTextInput="textBoxValue_PreviewTextInput" DataObject.Pasting="textBoxValue_Pasting" MaxLength="2" FontSize="15px"/>
        <Label Content="Minutos" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="651,258,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="29" Width="71" FontSize="15px"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Minutos4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="750,258,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.906,0.034" Height="29" Width="38" PreviewTextInput="textBoxValue_PreviewTextInput" DataObject.Pasting="textBoxValue_Pasting" MaxLength="2" FontSize="15px"/>

        <Label Content="Alarma 5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="614,324,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.487,0.445"/>
        <Label Content="Horas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="477,363,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="59" FontSize="15px"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Horas5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="570,363,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.906,0.034" Height="29" Width="37" PreviewTextInput="textBoxValue_PreviewTextInput" DataObject.Pasting="textBoxValue_Pasting" MaxLength="2" FontSize="15px"/>
        <Label Content="Minutos" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="652,363,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="29" Width="71" FontSize="15px"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Minutos5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="751,363,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.906,0.034" Height="29" Width="38" PreviewTextInput="textBoxValue_PreviewTextInput" DataObject.Pasting="textBoxValue_Pasting" MaxLength="2" FontSize="15px"/>

        <Button Content="Aplicar Cambios" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,552,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="113" Height="28" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem here is that you are not returning from the timer's `Tick` event handler until the user has dismissed the message box. The timer won't issue another `Tick` event until you are done handling the current one.

Instead of showing the message box in the event handler itself, you should show it asynchronously, by using the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` method:

```
    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblTime.Content = Convert.ToDateTime(lblTime.Content).AddSeconds(1).ToLongTimeString();
        int btr = sp.BytesToRead;
        if (btr != 0)
        {
            string alarma = char.ConvertFromUtf32(sp.ReadChar());

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => 
                MessageBox.Show("La alarma " + alarma + " se activo", "Alarma",
                    MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation)));
        }
    }
```

This will wrap your method call in a delegate, which is in turn enqueued to be executed at a later time in the same thread (the Dispatcher thread). This allows the `Tick` event handler to return, so that the timer can continue running.

That said, your code isn't quite right. IMHO, the most obvious, most important problem to fix is that timers (all of them) are not very inaccurate. They can (as you've seen) be delayed for a variety of reasons, and are not scheduled for execution very precisely. Over time, your clock is very likely to drift from the actual time you want to display.

Instead, you should use e.g. an instance of `Stopwatch`, starting it when you want the clock to start, adding its `Elapsed` value to your initial value (i.e. `new TimeSpan(0, intHoras, intMinutos + 2)`, which you could calculate once and store in a class field for that purpose), and displaying that sum with an appropriate explicit format string (e.g. `"hh:mm:ss tt"`).

**Edit:**

This is really secondary to the original question, but since you asked…

A better way to track the time for your clock would be as follows:

1. Add two new fields to your class:

```
private TimeSpan baseTime;
private Stopwatch elapsed;
```

2. Initialize these fields when you start the timer:

```
baseTime = new TimeSpan(0, intHoras, intMinutos + 2);
elapsed = Stopwatch.StartNew();
```

3. Then use those values to display the time in the timer's `Tick` event handler:

```
lblTime.Content = (baseTime + elapsed.Elapsed).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```

Naturally, you will remove other code related to the display of the time: the `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` local variables in the initialization code, and the existing statement that sets `lblTime.Content` in the `Tick` event handler method.

Finally, in case it will appease Hans's opposition to `Stopwatch`, you could implement the above using only `DateTime` instead. That is, instead of the above, do something like this:

1. Add two new fields to your class:

```
private TimeSpan baseTime;
private DateTime startTime;
```

2. Initialize these fields when you start the timer:

```
baseTime = new TimeSpan(0, intHoras, intMinutos + 2);
startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

3. Then use those values to display the time in the timer's `Tick` event handler:

```
lblTime.Content = (baseTime + (DateTime.UtcNow - startTime)).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```

Note that `UtcNow` relies on the system clock, so if it changes, that will affect the displayed elapsed time, causing it to be incorrect. For example, if the user changes the set time, or the system automatically updates the clock from a NTP server (the only way that automatically adjusting the clock from an NTP server will *improve* the displayed time is if the system clock has drifted farther from the correct time than it had already drifted when the counter in your program was started…this is not a very common scenario).

Comment: Hmm, we've been through this before.  Don't use Stopwatch to measure elapsed wall-clock time, it is very precise but not [accurate enough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision).  Just store DateTime.UtcNow when the timer is started.  Subtract it from DateTime.UtcNow to get accurate elapsed time.

Comment: @HansPassant: yes, we have been through this before. And your advice is just as wrong now as it was before. UtcNow will change for a variety of reasons -- some of these changes may help accuracy, but others hurt it -- and is not reliable for measuring elapsed time. I provided a number of references to you the last time around, including an article by Eric Lippert (I know you don't respect my opinion, but his is well-established as a reliable one). Those references still hold and refute your claim.

Comment: @PeterDuniho thank you for the Dispatcher solution it worked for me. But I dont understand the Stopwatch solution. Because I need to start the clock from defined numbers in the textbox, and updated it in the label in real-time. You can explain me how to do that?

Comment: @PeterDuniho I have an FormatException in the line `lblTime.Content = (baseTime + elapsed.Elapsed).ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");` the error is: An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: @SebastiánA: sorry about that...I forgot to update the format string to account for the change from `DateTime` to `TimeSpan`. Please see my edited answer for the correct format strings (note that these do not display AM/PM, since that's not something that `TimeSpan` tracks...since your initialization code is based on `TimeSpan` and not `DateTime`, I assume that's fine).

Comment: @PeterDuniho And if my code is based on Date Time how can I put the AM/PM?

Comment: @SebastiánA: then you would change `TimeSpan baseTime;` to `DateTime baseTime;` (initialized appropriately of course, possibly as you were before) and use the format string I gave earlier: `"hh:mm:ss tt"`. Note that in that case, you probably are _not_ displaying elapsed time per se; it's not clear in that case why you would need `baseTime` at all, rather than just display the current system clock time.